# Positioning with javascripted Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys I'm struggling to complete my sliding Nav bar. The problem now is I don't know how to change the tab images between sliding the bar out and back in (as seen in the picture). The image for folding it back in has to be inside the nav bar itself which is where I'm confused, could anyone help?

My link is here (with the help from Ketan) jsfiddle.net/6y90wkju/6/ (sorry have to copy and paste wont let me insert jsfiddle link without code)

Here's a picture...
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following way. You didn't include JQuery in your fiddle so it didn't work.

Give `overflow:hidden;` to `#Maincontainer` and also animate `#slide` with `.hidden` container.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.hidden');

    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-228px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
        $('#slide').animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
        $('#slide').animate({"left":"228px"}, "slow");
    }
    });
});
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/6y90wkju/8/)

Comment: You are legit THE MAN Cheers Ketan!

Comment: Now all I need to do is get the first tab to turn into the second tab once pulled out...See what I mean? I'll post again if you're busy :)

Comment: Sorry i didn't getting you.

Comment: in the picture there are two different buttons for activating the nav bar. Bringing it out is one and folding it back in is another that is placed inside the nav bar, hopefully that makes sense?

In the fiddle examples we're just using text for a filler.

Comment: Yes sort of, is there a way of using images instead of text and for folding the nav bar away having the image inside the navbar itself. The images for both are the same just one is outside and one is inside like the picture. Really hope this makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77954/discussion-between-ketan-and-marcus-porter).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this solution

JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1dh4v5tj/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slide').click(function(){
     var hidden = $('.hidden');
     if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
  hidden.animate({"left":"-180px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible').find("#slide").text("Show");
} else {
       hidden.animate({"left":"0"}, "slow").addClass('visible').find("#slide").text("Hide");

}
});


});
```

Comment: Hmm I like it, but does that mean the nav bar would have to be out a little constantly for it to work?

Comment: Not necessarily but the image you shared had a projection, so incorporated the same.

Comment: ooo I like that better, is there a way of hiding the "show" box once clicked so you don't see the nav bar sliding over it?

Comment: Awesome man! Looks like I have two great answers....can't pick one to go with! haha.